# How can I write vertical character with underline in html?

Tags: html, css

As I show in following picture, I want it display in html, vertical align character with underline. Please notice the direction of each character,which means I can't use `<br>`, because when you use `<br>`, the direction of character does not change. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/YjwCq/8/ ?

Comment: @KingKing, a improved version : http://jsfiddle.net/YjwCq/9/

Comment: @Jamie I've never added all the prefixes for a simple demo (maybe I'm a little lazy), there is a high chance people use Chrome or Opera now, otherwise he should understand to change the prefix himself.

Comment: No every body, knows about cross-browser solution. Even including these two attributes, in some browser it may even not be supported. The purpose is to let him know the importance of cross-browser support.

Comment: @Jamie have you ever heard about **prefix FREE**? A newbie need an idea not a cross-browser solution, I don't have time to copy and paste to make a complete demo like so. and don't SHOUT like that. In actual implementation, we should use the so-called **prefix FREE**, we don't have to type all the prefixes which makes the CSS long and hard to maintain.

Comment: Thanks you two, I think your solution is good enough.

Comment: The image is misleading, because the text in it is not vertical and it is not underlined.